# Facebook Open Graph Friend Array results are limited

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I'm retrieving an array of my users' friends' ids using open graph api.

```
 $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=2000');
 $friendsList = array();
            foreach ($friends as $key=>$value) 
            {
               foreach ($value as $fkey=>$fvalue) {

                   $friendsList[] = $fvalue[id];
               }

            }
```

The problem I have is that no matter what I put in the limit, I only receive a max of 500 friend id values for users that have more than 500 friends.  I have been reading up on limits and pagination in Facebook Developers information with no luck.

Any ideas on what I need to do to retrieve all user's friend ID's?  Why does the last value in the array show as "h"?  All other values are id's.

THANKS!!!

Comment: So what happens when you follow the pagination links in the response?
What problem are you encountering when you call `/me/friends?limit-500&offset=500`?

Comment: I tried that and got  Array ( [0] => h )

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the last value in the array show as "h"?

Because you are doing a loop in a loop.

In the outer loop, you iterate over the two properties of the actual API response – `data` and `paging`.

And then, in the inner loop, you go through each of the arrays these properties point to. That’s a lot of results in the form of name and id; and then the second time the inner loop goes through the array that the `paging` property points to, and that has only one property that has the name/key `next` and the value `https://graph.facebook.com/…`

Now, since you are trying index-based access on the first value with `$fvalue[id]`, since `$fvalue` contains actually the text literal `https://graph.facebook.com/…`, and there is no contant named `id` declared, PHP first interprets that as if `"id"` was ment, and then converts this string value to integer `0` for index-based access on `$fvalue`. And that gets you – since PHP also allows access to bytes (*not* characters) in a string variable index-based – the first byte, whose ASCII representation is the character `h` …

---

So, what you *want* to do is loop actually just once, but directly over the contents of `$friends['data']`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I don't know what I'd do without being able to reference this website.  Here's what I did to get rid of the "h" problem.....I'm still limited to 500 id's even with my limit set to 5000.

     $frindslist2= array();
          foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
                 $friendslist2[] = $friend['id'];
                  }

I then implode the array with a comma to list results.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need facebook id then you should try with just id field, it should return all the friends id. with this I remember my app has handled a user with 1500 friends.

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=id');
```